# Rank-ordered logit model: question

Tags: econometrics, ordered-logit, ranks

I have a dataset in which each individual ranks four attributes of a product. This task (with the same attributes) is repeated three times under different conditions. The product is still the same, so I have only individuals’ characteristics as variables.
The rank-ordinal logit model seems to be the natural method. However, I was wondering if there are some statistical methods that allows to determine if the individuals ranking is consistent across the three different situations. Moreover, which method suits the most? I was thinking to:
if exists a sort of panel data rank-ordered logit
estimates three different rank-ordered logit and then test for equality of parameters across the three estimations
use the three ranking to obtain one unique ranking for each individuals, and then applied the rank-ordered logit

Thank you for your attention

Answer (score 1):

This is probably a place for a proportional odds mixed effects model (see e.g. the `ordinal` package in R).  Per-subject random effects handle the non-independence of responses within a subject.  I don't know how to model across-time agreement per se but it would be easy to include a linear time effect in the mixed model (time would be a fixed effect) to assess drift in the typical responses across time.

Comment: Thank you Frank for your reply. However I have a doubt: does the proportional odds mixed effects model work when the dependent variable is an ordinal one? Because I have a ranking as d.v.

Comment: @Andrea yes it does. If you use R see the package Frank cited and its documentation.

Comment: @mdewey thank you. The fact is that my d.v is not ordinal but is a ranking. Here (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ordinal/ordinal.pdf) I don't find my case

Comment: @Andrea as far as I can see a ranking is a subset of ordered categorical variables.

Comment: I think that in an ordered regression, the respondent, for example, provides an answer to a question among different level (for example very likely, likely, unlikely, very unlikely). In the rank ordered the respondent faces different alternative and ranks them, so it's a kind of specification of a multinomial logit model, with the difference that respondents instead of choosing the best alternative, ranks them (providing so more information)

Comment: True that the most typical use of ordinal response models is for a originally-ordinal variable Y.  But if Y resulted from a ranking this also creates an ordinal Y and the model seems to still be a good choice.  I am ignoring the small negative correlation that is induced (if you rank something very high the other observations have to be ranked lower).